# $9$ beads on $3$ by $3$ grid such that two of the beads are not adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to put $9$ differently colored beads on a $3\times3$ grid if the purple bead and the green bead cannot be adjacent (either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally), and rotations and reflections of the grid are considered the same?

I do not see a clear application of Burnside's Lemma because of the restriction that the beads can not be adjacent. I think that maybe casework or something would be good, but I can not do it due the number of cases. Are there any smart and slick solutions?

I tried making some progress on this question:

If the grid is denoted as follows:

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&1& &2& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&7& &8& &9&\\
\end{array}

Sorry for the bad alignment that is about to follow. Then the possible configurations are (please correct me if I am wrong)

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&P& &2& &G&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&7& &8& &9&\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&P& &2& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&7& &8& &G&\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&P& &2& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&G& &8& &9&\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&1& &P& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&7& &G& &9&\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&1& &P& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&G& &8& &9&\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
&1& &G& &3&\\
&4& &5& &6&\\
&P& &8& &9&\\
\end{array}

I am stuck here. Cases $1$ and $3$ are identical, case $5$ and $6$ are identical, and cases $2$ and cases $4$ are separate (unless they are equal)? Can someone help me apply Burnside's Lemma?!

Comment: Let's say we were placing the green bead(we can have the same argument for the purple bead). Notice that the green bead can't be in the middle. Because of symmetry, that  leaves two cases, placing it in the corner, and placing it on the other spots(the "middle" spot on the sides).

Comment: Please see case 2 of the answer that I posted to another similar question (not same). It should give you enough ideas. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808924/painting-a-different-board-in-a-particular-way

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. But how do you combine the cases with the rotations and reflections?

Comment: HINT: I think you're over-thinking this.  Burnside's Lemma is not needed here.  For every valid square, all $8$ symmetries are distinct because the $9$ beads are all different colors.  Is this homework?  Please let us know so we can provide the appropriate level of help.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the purple nor the green bead can be put at the center of the grid. It follows that any placement of the beads can be transformed by reflections and rotations to exactly one of the following five groups $P_{ij}$ of placements, where the purple bead is placed at $i$ and the green bead is placed at $j$: $P_{13}$, $P_{16}$, $P_{19}$, $P_{27}$, and $P_{28}$. Each of groups $P_{13}$, $P_{16}$, and $P_{26}$ consists of $7!$ placements, because the placement of beads different from green and purple can be arbitrary.
Each of groups $P_{19}$ and $P_{28}$ consists of $7!/2$ placements, because the placement of beads different from green and purple splits into subgroups consisting of two symmetric placements (with the same positions of the purple and the green bead).  So there are $3\cdot 7!+2\cdot 7!/2=4\cdot 7!=20160$ unique bead  placements in total.

Comment: I've always enjoyed your answers but I think today you made a rare error.  ;)  You're double-counting the $(1,9)$ case.  Half of those $7!$ replacements are reflections (across the main diagonal) of the other half.  Same for the $(2,8)$ case.

Comment: @antkam Oops, you are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I finally understand! This is amazing!

Comment: You're welcome @AlexRavsky - BTW I actually trusted you so much that originally I thought your old answer must be right and my answer (see below) must be wrong.  But eventually I figured out where your old answer went wrong.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way / fuller explanation of my comment to the main thread.

I will use the term **position** to refer to one of the $9!$ possible arrangements of beads onto $9$ squares.

You want to count **equivalent classes**, where two positions belong to the same class if they are reflections/rotations of each other.  This problem is very simple because every class has $8$ positions, and more importantly, *either all $8$ are valid or all $8$ are invalid*.  So you can ignore all thinking about symmetry, and just count valid positions (i.e. treating reflections/rotations as *distinct*) and then divide by $8$.  This is what I meant by "Burnside's Lemma is not needed."

- If purple bead is at $1$, green can be at $3,6,7,8,9$.  So there are $5 \times 7!$ such positions.
- If purple bead is at $2$, green can be at $7,8,9$, so $3 \times 7!$ such positions.
- If purple bead is at $3$, green can be at $1,4,7,8,9$, so $5 \times 7!$ such positions.
- Etc.

In total there are $(5+3 + 5 + 3 + 0 + 3 + 5 + 3 + 5) \times 7! = 32 \times 7!$ valid positions.  Divide by $8$ and you get $4 \times 7!$ equivalent classes.

If you want to use symmetry-based thinking, the answer by Alex Ravsky is the way to go, but for this particular problem, that way is actually a bit more subtle and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

$ N = \biggl( \frac{T - A} {D} \biggr)$
where $\begin{cases}
N = \text{total # of unique valid arrangements.} \\
T = \text{total # of possible arrangements.} \\
A = \text{# cases where green & purple marbles are adjacent.}\\
D = \text{# "repeated" board states due to rotation & reflection.} \\
\end{cases}$

$ $
$T = \ _9P_9 = \frac{9!} {(9-9)!} = 9! = 362,880$

$ $
$A = A_{middle} + A_{corner} + A_{side} $
where $\begin{cases}
A_{middle} = \text{# adjacency cases when green marble is in middle.} \\
A_{corner} = \text{# adjacency cases when green marble is in a corner.} \\
A_{side} = \text{# adjacency cases when green marble is on a side.} \\
\end{cases}$
*Note that we only consider these cases for one marble (either green or purple, but not both), because doing so for one accounts for all the cases in which the other colored marble occupies each position.
Example: A case in which green is in the corner is also a case in which purple is on a side.
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 G & P & \ \ \   \\\hline
  &  & \ \ \   \\\hline
  &  & \ \ \  
\end{array}$
The opposite case is encountered when considering the following case in which green is on a side:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 P & G & \ \ \   \\\hline
  &  & \ \ \   \\\hline
  &  & \ \ \  
\end{array}$

When the green marble occupies the middle position, there are 8 possible locations for the purple marble wherein it is adjacent to the green. For each of these adjacencies, there are 7 other positions which are filled by the 7 other marbles.
$A_{middle} = 8 \Bigl( \ _7P_7 \Bigr) = 8 \Bigl( \frac{7!} {(7-7)!} \Bigr) =          
8(7!) = 8(5040) = 40,320$

When the green marble occupies a corner position, of which there are 4, there are 3 possible locations for the purple marble in which it is adjacent to the green. For every such position, there are 7 other positions which are filled by the 7 other marbles.
$A_{corner} = 4 \biggl( 3 \bigl( \ _7P_7 \bigr) \biggr) =                                 4 \biggl( 3 \Bigl( \frac{7!} {(7-7)!} \Bigr) \biggr) =                                    
4 \biggl( 3 \Bigl( 7! \Bigr) \biggr) = 4 \biggl( 3 \Bigl( 5040 \Bigr) \biggr) =           
4 \biggl( 15120 \biggr) = 60,480$

When the green marble occupies a side position, of which there are 4, there are 5 possible locations for the purple marble in which it is adjacent to the green. For every such position, there are 7 other positions which are filled by the 7 other marbles.
$A_{side} = 4 \biggl( 5 \bigl( \ _7P_7 \bigr) \biggr) =                                 
4 \biggl( 5 \Bigl( 5040 \Bigr) \biggr) = 100,800$

$A = 40,320 + 60,480 + 100,800 = 201,600$

$ $
$ $
$\underline{ \text{Calculating } D \text{ } }$

For every "original" board state of the form:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 1 & 2 & 3   \\\hline
 4 & 5 & 6   \\\hline
 7 & 8 & 9 
\end{array}$

$\Rightarrow$ There are 3 "identical" boards due to rotation (each board is a $ \ 90°$ rotation clockwise from the previous):

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 7 & 4 & 1   \\\hline
 8 & 5 & 2   \\\hline
 9 & 6 & 3 
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 9 & 8 & 7   \\\hline
 6 & 5 & 4   \\\hline
 3 & 2 & 1 
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 3 & 6 & 9   \\\hline
 2 & 5 & 8   \\\hline
 1 & 4 & 7 
\end{array}$

$ $
$\Rightarrow$ There are 4 "identical" boards due to reflection (assuming reflection is across the $x$ and $y$ axes, and across the diagonal lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$):

Reflection across the $x$-axis:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 7 & 8 & 9   \\\hline
 4 & 5 & 6   \\\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{array}$

Reflection across the $y$-axis:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 3 & 2 & 1   \\\hline
 6 & 5 & 4   \\\hline
 9 & 8 & 7 
\end{array}$

Reflection across the line $y=x$:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 1 & 4 & 7   \\\hline
 2 & 5 & 8   \\\hline
 3 & 6 & 9 
\end{array}$

Reflection across the line $y=-x$:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 9 & 6 & 3   \\\hline
 8 & 5 & 2   \\\hline
 7 & 4 & 1 
\end{array}$

$ $
Since we know that $T$ accounts for $\mathit{every}$ possible board state, we know that there are 7 other "identical" instances for any given board state (due to rotations and reflections). Then, each of these sets-of-8 (1 "original" + 3 rotation "copies" + 4 reflection "copies) can be considered the same element, which reduces $T$ by a factor of 8.

$D = 8$

$ $

Finally, we can calculate the value of $N$ from the first equation:

$ N = \biggl( \frac{T - A} {D} \biggr) = \Bigl( \frac{362,880 - 201,600} {8} \Bigr) =            
 \frac{161,280} {8} = 20,160$

$\Rightarrow$    
$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
N = 20,160
}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Nice formatting and very detailed but there are two errors, unfortunately.  First, an arithmetic error:  $A_{middle} = 8 \times 7! = 40320$.  Second, a more serious error: $D$ should be $8$, not $6$ because there are two reflections across diagonals (which can also be considered as combining a rotation with an orthogonal reflection).  These are the well known $8$ symmetries of the square.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know if they wanted diagonal reflections or not since they didn't specify in the question statement; I went ahead and updated the charts and the value for $D$, and I'll keep this in mind for next time. As for the miscalculation, I have no idea how that one slipped by me .
I went ahead and updated everything, and it looks like my final answer matches up with the other answer.
Thanks again, and have a nice day!